# Getting error: type or namespace name "SelectList" could not be found

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm using ASP.NET Core MVC and Visual Studio 2019 and I'm getting this error message over this line of code written in my Controller file:

```
public ActionResult Edit()
{
    ViewData["Email1"] = new SelectList(dbContext.GetList().ToList(), "Email", "Email");
    return View();
}
```

I installed this nuget package:

```
Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc
```

And I'm using this code:

```
using System.web.Mvc
```

It seems there is a problem on that package:

[image]

I've been searching and i found something related to "Clean your solution and then set the property of those files to Copy Local = True." but i could not find the References folder on VS2019

Can help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use asp.net core
Get rid of using System.Web.Mvc; if you still have.

Add using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering ; Install a nuget package

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures -Version 2.2.0
```

if you have an syntax error. Or if it installed try to use it explicitely:

```
 ViewData["Email1"] = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.SelectList(....
```

and what is this:

```
dbContext.GetList().ToList()
```

It doesn't look like a valid list, it could give the errors.

Comment: Hey pal. I added that line of code but still getting the same error message :/

Comment: System.Web.Mvc is already gone :(

Comment: I'm still getting the same error message, these are the libraries in used:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc and Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering

Comment: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.SelectList does not exist, it only shows me Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering

Comment: If i use Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.SelectList then SelectList does not appear anymore

Comment: I am sorry but I have created hundrends SelectLists using this namespace and never had any problems.

Comment: No, i swear :(, i do not know what is going on

Comment: I'm gonna upload my code, i'm trying to create a DropDownList

Comment: Drop down list uses SelectListItem from the same namespace.

Comment: Thank you, i was able to solve it

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing .Net Core app, you should use `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering`

SelectList class is a member of the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc library in .Net Core

Comment: Hey pal. No, it is already installed and i'm getting the same error :/

Comment: Remove Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc package

Comment: Okay, it was deleted but still the same problem